# Anchor tags not changing URL

Tags: html

I have some anchor links with text and radio button.

On clicking text or radio button the URL should change. But this is not happening.
When I click the text or radio button the radio button is checked but URL is not changed.

Here is the code:

```
 <ul>
     <li>
        <a href="#page-1">
            <label for="page-1">Page 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="page-1" name="page" />
        </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#page-2">
            <label for="page-2">Page 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="page-2" name="page" />
        </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

So on clicking one of these 2 items the URL should change like `www.website.com/#first-page`

I tried to remove `for="page-1"` and tried to remove `<li>` and replace it with `<a>`. But didn't work.

Why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

It is forbidden to nest interactive elements (like links and radio buttons).

If you want a link, use a link. If you want a radio button, use a radio button.

If you want a link that looks like a radio button then first stop, reconsider if you really want a UI that doesn't behave like UIs that look that way are expected to behave and, if you really want to do something like that: simulate the radio button with an image.